# wp_usermeta query hanging for a few seconds before loading

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a query that I wrote a couple of years ago for a membership website.  I'm not extremely well versed in using $wpdb (or MYSQL code in general) to write custom queries, and the site has grown quite a bit.  There are about 150k rows in the wp_usermeta table now, and the page where the query runs hangs for a couple of seconds now before loading.  I expect that this will get worse as time goes on and the site gains more users.

Any help in figuring out how to speed this query up would be greatly appreciated.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$limit = 15;
$offset = ($paged - 1) * $limit;
$key = 'first_name';

$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS {$wpdb->users}.* FROM {$wpdb->users}
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} wp_usermeta ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = '$key'
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_value <> ''
    AND wp_users.user_registered < '2014-01-30'
ORDER BY wp_usermeta.meta_value ASC
LIMIT $offset, $limit";

$members = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$found_rows = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();");

foreach ($members as $member) { // display member info here }
```

*Note: I am paginating...not displaying all results on one page.

Comment: Can we see an EXPLAIN, and proper DDLs for the relevant tables?

Comment: If I'm reading this right it returns a row for every user with a first_name in wp_postmeta, in order of first name. But it doesn't actually return the first name.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

First, you seem to be ordering by user first name, but not retrieving or displaying it. That's a bit odd. You could order by wp_users.user_nicename, and omit the join to wp_usermeta.  That will save some time in joining. That column's value is set by the user in her profile, and reflects the identity by which she wants to be known. So, it's an appropriate ordering column, most likely.

Second, you're retrieving all the columns (*) in wp_users. Can you avoid retrieving them all, and rather enumerate the one you actually need? That will save time in sorting.

Your query would become this.

```
 $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                id, user_login, user_nicename, etc etc
           FROM {$wpdb->users}
          WHERE user_registered < '2014-01-30'
          ORDER BY user_nicename ASC
          LIMIT $offset, $limit";
```

You are stuck, as you are paginating a large number of users, with some inescapable inefficiency. But this should be better than what you have.

Comment: The client is (unavoidably) using a membership plugin which registers users with the email address being the username and, by default, the nicename.  Most users don't change it.  Thus, I need to do the inner join in order to be able to order by first name.  That said, it seems that just calling ID and user_registered from wp_users is making a noticeable difference.  Thanks for the help.